# Notation used in time series

Tags: time-series, notation

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) wikipedia article about the concept of stationarity in stochastic processes.

Let $\left\{X_t\right\}$ be a stochastic process and let $F_{X}(x_{t_1 + \tau}, \ldots, x_{t_n + \tau})$ represent the cumulative distribution function of the unconditional (i.e., with no reference to any particular starting value) joint distribution of $\left\{X_t\right\}$ at times $t_1 + \tau, \ldots, t_n + \tau$.

I do not understand what the notation $x_{t_{1}}$ means. The usual way of defining a time series would be to index a variable with a time value $t$ as in $x_{t}$. Intuitively this would denote what the value of the time series is at time period $t$. Why the need to add another index integer under the $t$?

Comment: But if you have to make reference to multiple, arbitrary times, how else would you do it? The process is considered at times $t_1$, $t_2$,..., $t_n$.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, you could make a brief answer out of your comment.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, does it mean that $t_{1}$ is the first in a sequence of arbitrary periods. For example $t_{1}$ could be equal to  $11$ and then $t_{2} =  12 , ... t_{n} =  20 $